# Why is the assigned stack frame size is different for malloc() and normal array declaration?

Tags: c, recursion, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

I have two very simple recursive C programs. I was checking the stack frame size assigned by the system to each recursive frame. But I came across something I did not understand.

- When I create a local array with size 5 in the recursive function, then the system assigns 48 bytes to each frame.
- When I create a pointer and assign the same amount of memory with `size*sizeof()`, then the system assigns 32 bytes to each frame.

The way I check is, I compile my C code into assembly and see the bytes allocated. My guess for the difference is that `malloc` assigns from heap and normal array declaration assigns from the stack. So I am thinking these two memory parts might have different procedures?

I was expecting the memory allocated to be the same but they are different.

I call them from the main function.

```c
void RecursiveFunction( int n )
{
    int *point;
    point = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);

    if ( n > 1)
        RecursiveFunction( --n );
    return;
}
```

and

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void RecursiveFunction( int n )
{
    int arr[5];

    if ( recursion_times > 1)
        RecursiveFunction( --n );

    return;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++: local array definition versus a malloc call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3269627/11683)

Comment: Assuming the "zero" frame size of 28 bytes, in the first case you have `28 + sizeof(int*)`, which on your system is 32, and in the second it is `28 + sizeof(int) * 5`, which is 48.

Comment: But we assign extra memory with (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5). Does that not take up space?

Comment: `sizeof(int)*5` bytes is allocated from the heap. On the stack there is only a pointer to that (`int*`).

Comment: Thank you so much, that solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness:

`malloc` allocates space from the *heap*, whereas local variables are allocated on the *stack*.  Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes, your array takes up 4*5=20 bytes.  When you allocate the array using `malloc`, the actual array isn't part of the stack frame, but the pointer where you restore the address returned by `malloc` *is*, which explains why the difference in stack frame size is 20-4=16.